# Is there a way to check how many times an ERC721 token has been minted?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix, ethers.js, hardhat

I am using the OpenZeppelin's ERC721 Library, is there was a way to get the count of the number of times a token has been minted.

Is there a built-in mapping or function to check that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Enumerable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol) extension. The `totalSupply()` function returns the currently existing amount of tokens (minted minus burned), which in some cases might not the same thing as the total amount of minted tokens.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Burnable.sol";

/*
 * `totalSupply()` (defined in ERC721Enumerable) returns 1
 * even though 2 tokens were minted, but 1 was also burned
 */
contract MyCollection is ERC721Enumerable, ERC721Burnable {
    constructor() ERC721("CollectionName", "Symbol") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1);
        _burn(1);
        _mint(msg.sender, 2);
    }

    // multiple parents define the same function
    // overriding here just to point at the expected parent class
    // related to the combination of `Burnable` and `Enumerable` in the same contract - not to `Enumerable` alone
    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable) {
        return ERC721Enumerable._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    // same reason for overriding as above
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable) returns (bool) {
        return ERC721Enumerable.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
}
```

Or you can override the `_beforeTokenTransfer()` hook and create a custom counter that takes into account only minting and ignores burning.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Burnable.sol";

/*
 * `mintCounter` returns 2, ignores the burned tokens
 */
contract MyCollection is ERC721Enumerable, ERC721Burnable {
    uint256 public mintCounter;

    constructor() ERC721("CollectionName", "Symbol") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1);
        _burn(1);
        _mint(msg.sender, 2);
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable) {
        if (from == address(0)) {
            mintCounter++;
        }

        return ERC721Enumerable._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable) returns (bool) {
        return ERC721Enumerable.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
}
```